# How to document argument that takes multiple types

Tags: python, comments, python-2.x

In Python 2, is there a canonical way to document that a method may be more than one type?

Here's how I've done it:

```
def __init__(self, work_order_number):
    """This message communicates that a job is being rerun.  Olio will
    forget everything it knows about the job.

    Args:
        work_order_number (int or str): Work order number
    """
    payload = {
        'work_order_number': str(work_order_number),
    }
    self.content = json.dumps(payload)
```

where I used the notation `(int or str)` to indicate that the argument may be either an integer or a string.

How do Python 2 programs usually document that a method argument can be of more than one type?  Is there a standard or best practice?

*Due to forces beyond my control, I cannot use Python 3 and therefore cannot use annotations*

Comment: That looks OK to me. There isn't much canonical around docstrings bar [PEP-257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) - as long as you are consistent within your project (and the strictures of anything generating documentation from them) you are fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you did it is fine.  There is no exact format that is necessary; you just need to make the intent clear using commas or "or".  See for instance various functions from [`matplotlib`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html) or [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html) which take arguments documented "str or None", "float, sequence or None", "list-like or integer", etc.